# Relay force fetch for the entire client store

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I have notification system in my app and i want to fetch data when new notification comes. I use

`` RelayStore.forceFetch({statusRequest: Relay.QL`{query { viewer { list { edges ...}}}`}) ``

So it works for nodes, because a node has ID, but for exist connections it doesn't. In documentation it says

`forceFetch can be called with an empty set of partial variables, meaning it can trigger a refresh of the currently rendered set of data.`

I am trying to fetch only a connection with an empty array as set of partial variables. It did nothing. In network tab i see my request to the server and in the response i see that data was fetched correctly. But in response i see `list: ...`. It fetches new connection, not exists one. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: There is a github issue about forceFetch not working with connection, which  was fixed later. Please check your [version number](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/655#issuecomment-192867677).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem that i call forceFetch from `react-relay/lib/RelayStore` not from component. I want to update whole current state. I wanna smth like refresh().